# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Tags: php, freetype, php-gd, freetype2

Why am I getting the error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagettftext()` on line 29?

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$strings = '123456789';
$i = 0;
$characters = 6;
$code = '';
while ($i < $characters)
{ 
    $code .= substr($strings, mt_rand(0, strlen($strings)-1), 1);
    $i++;
} 

$_SESSION['captcha'] = $code;

//generate image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(124, 40);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$shadow = imagecolorallocate($im, 173, 172, 168);
$background = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 200, $background);

// use your own font!
$font = 'monofont.ttf';

//draw text:
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 9, 28, $shadow, $font, $code);
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 2, 32, $foreground, $font, $code);     

// prevent client side  caching
header("Expires: Wed, 1 Jan 1997 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

//send image to browser
header ("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>`
```

**My PHP Info:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because ... there's no such function defined?

Comment: Googling "imagettftext" brings up ... http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=6410

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to the [PHP manual entry for `imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#refsect1-function.imagettftext-notes):

> This function requires both the GD library and the » FreeType library.

You must be missing one or both of the required libraries in your PHP build.

Comment: @Jess McKenzie: Please show us the "Configure Command" part of `phpinfo()` too.

Comment: Where to add these libraries? I am using `heroku` with custom `buildpack`.

Comment: Just in case someone is searching for this and is using WHM, run /scripts/easyapache and select TTF Freetype from the Exhaustive Options List and recompile.

Answer (score 41):

I solve the same issue on my docker `php:7-fpm` enviroment, and I post the solution here:

---

#### If using `Dockerfile` to setup the enviroment

```
# more Dockerfile  
FROM php:fpm 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev
    && docker-php-ext-install iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
        --with-png-dir=/usr/include \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd
```

#### If want to add the FreeType module on an exist container:

```
# on docker host machine
docker exec -it $FPM_CONTAINER bash

>>>>

# inside the container
apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev
docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
        --with-png-dir=/usr/include \
        --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd

exit

<<<<

docker restart $FPM_CONTAINER
```

Comment: Amazing, just the answer I was looking for.

Comment: great, but I need to take away the last command `docker-php-ext-install` -- is that a copy-paste-typo?

Comment: @Alexander well, it's a mistake, I've removed that, thank you.

Comment: Is `vim` really needed for `imagettftext` support or just a copy-paste remainder? Also is `opcache` related to the inquiry?

Comment: @YoanTournade Thank you for pointing that out, the answer is updated.

Comment: Error: libpng12-dev no candidate to install.

Answer (score 6):

For a Docker container with PHP 7.4, use these commands to install the extension:

```
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype
docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Using the previous approach results in:

```
configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-freetype-dir
```

[Relevant comment.](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/865#issuecomment-511583850)

Comment: Also works for docker containers with `php:8-apache`.

Answer (score 4):

Just recompile extension gd.so, under folder `php/ext/gd`

> `./configure
>   --with-php-config=/usr/local/php5/bin/php-config --with-freetype-dir=/usr/ --enable-gd-native-ttf`

Answer (score 4):

For a Docker container with an Apache 7.3 , the following is working for me:

```
FROM php:7.3.10-apache

RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
     --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
     --with-png-dir=/usr/include \
     --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include \
  && docker-php-ext-install gd
```

It's basically a cleaned up version as provided by Alfred Huang - without `mcrypt` and `mbstring`.

Comment: Also works fine with `php:7.3-fpm`. This supposed to work fine with all `php7.3` variations I guess.