# imagettfbbox() Cant Open .ttf font

Tags: php

I have This **Error:**

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function imagettfbbox() in
>   **/home/example/public_html/generate.php** on line **65**

Line **65 of generate.php** :

`63- $code = $this->generateCode();`

`64- $font = _ROOT_PATH_ . '/Captcha/ccf.ttf';`

`65- imagettfbbox(138, 0, $font, $code);`

Help me plz :(

Comment: Do you have imagemagick installed?

Comment: OCULOUS REPARO! Did that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290958/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagettftext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

```
 This function requires both the GD library and the » FreeType library.
```

You must be missing one or both of the required libraries in your PHP build.

build file 'info.php' with this code:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

run it and see which are missing, then go and install it/them.

Answer (score 1):

To use the function "imagettfbbox" one must have both GD and FreeType. It seems, given the error one of those is missing.

[PHP.net imagettfbbox docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php)

Once they are both available the function should work.